# Probability that 5 heads occur in 8 tosses

Tags: probability

Suppose that you toss a coin until, for example, 5 heads occur. What would be the probability that it takes 8 tosses?

Comment: You want to read about the [negative binomial distiribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

Comment: You need the $8^{th}$ toss to be $H$ and you need exactly $4$ of the previous $7$ to be Heads as well, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[H or T ][H or T][H or T][H or T][H or T][H ot T][H or T][H]

First assume that the coin is fair so P(H) or P(T) = 1/2

The last tosses need to be H as we want it to occur in 8 tosses

So now we find all the combinations of 4 heads and 3 tails in the tosses

n choose k

(7 choose 4 ) 7!/4!3! = 35

All possible tosses combinations = 2^8 =256

P( H = 5 in 8 tosses ) = 35/256 = 0.1367

But if the coin is not fair YEAH as arthur mentioned https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Comment: That's if you know you're doing 8 tosses. The way i read the question, we're instead tossing until we get the fifth head. That's a different question. Doesn't matter whether the coin is fair.

Comment: You are right!! I am totally wrong

Answer (score 1):

The last toss must result in a head.

Further of the former $7$ tosses exactly $4$ must result in heads.

There are $\binom74$ possibilities and if the coin is fair then each of them has probability $2^{-8}$ to occur.

So the probability that exactly $8$ tosses are needed equals:$$\binom742^{-8}$$

Comment: That's if you know you're doing 8 tosses. The way i read the question, we're instead tossing until we get the fifth head. That's a different question.